# How to clean username with Django allauth adapter?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Django allauth validates usernames for illegal characters and uniqueness based on case insensitivity when signing up or logging in. That's great. But I would like to use the same validation on my own profile form that has a OneToOne with User. As it stands, I can't get the same logic in my Profile form.

I thought it might be importing `DefaultAccountAdapter` and overriding `def clean_username`, but I get:

```
TypeError at /accounts/profile/
clean_username() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

My `forms.py`:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

from .profiles.models import Profile


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'autocapitalize': 'off',
                    'autocorrect': 'off',
                    'placeholder': 'Username'
                }
            ),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'autocapitalize': 'words',
                    'autocorrect': 'off',
                    'placeholder': 'First name'
                }
            ),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'autocapitalize': 'words',
                    'autocorrect': 'off',
                    'placeholder': 'Last name'
                }
            ),
        }
        help_texts = {
            'username': '',
        }

    def clean_username(self, username):
        adapter = DefaultAccountAdapter()
        username = adapter.clean_username(username)
        return username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. Was overthinking it.

```
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter

#...

    def clean_username(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['username']
        value = get_adapter().clean_username(value)
        return value
```